# How to map the MAVEN data

Tags: matlab, plot, space, cdf, sql-server-mars

I need to use MAVEN satellite data to map the ionospheric structure of Mars. Now I have read the information in cdf file with matlab, but I don't know the meaning of these data and how to map these data to get the ionospheric structure of Mars. Please help answer, thank you.

I need to draw a picture of the structure of the Martian ionosphere. How do you do that？